# How can I create a pivot table from a resampled column?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Suppose I have event data like:

```
ts,uid
2016-02-13 20:18:03.000001 UTC,5236965070
2016-02-13 23:05:08 UTC,2834437228
2016-02-13 23:13:00.000032 UTC,2206245130
2016-02-13 22:45:07.000004 UTC,1539535012
2016-02-13 23:47:44 UTC,3431025028
2016-02-13 16:42:16.000001 UTC,810825324
2016-02-13 22:37:14 UTC,2625355144
2016-02-14 00:31:52.000009 UTC,24815453
2016-02-12 06:43:40.000007 UTC,3895095040
2016-02-14 00:09:04 UTC,715095136
...
```

How can I create a pivot table of the uid to the event count in the hour? I tried doing

> DF.groupby(['uid', pandas.TimeGrouper(key='ts', freq='h')], sort=False).count()

but I got `ValueError: items in new_categories are not the same as in old categories`. How can I get it to work? Is using `pivot` or `pivot_table` a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to access the hour from the timestamp using `dt.hour` (if your column isn't datetime already, convert it using `pd.to_datetime`):

```
In [90]: df.groupby([df.uid,df.ts.dt.hour]).count()
Out[90]:
               ts
uid        ts
24815453   0    1
715095136  0    1
810825324  16   1
1539535012 22   1
2206245130 23   1
2625355144 22   1
2834437228 23   1
3431025028 23   1
3895095040 6    1
5236965070 20   1
```

Note that the groupby "consumes" the uid column; if you want to avoid this you can use `as_index = False`.